# Como funciona a diretiva "#include"?

Tags: c, c++, include, preprocessador

O "include" do C++ faz o que exatamente?
Eu sei que ele "importa" um header/library. 
Mas se eu tenho um Header.h com:

```
#include <string>
using namespace std;
string a() {
return "PTSO";
}
```

e no Main.cpp:

```
#include <string>
#include "Header.h"
using namespace std;
int main() {
return 0;
}
```

O que exatamente estou importado do Header? Todo seu conteúdo?(includes...), ou apenas as funções?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Você está importando um texto. O que o compilador faz é simplificadamente o mesmo que você copiar e colar o texto que está dentro do *include* para dentro do texto que está no fonte principal.

Por isto a posição em que ele é incluso é importante. Quase sempre quando você não faz logo no início você está com problemas.

Ele está importando todo seu conteúdo. Normalmente esse conteúdo são apenas declarações de estruturas de dados (classes, estruturas, enumerações), constantes, cabeçalho de funções/métodos, macros e eventualmente algum código quando se deseja que uma função seja importada direto no fonte ao invés de ser chamada (*source inline*). O mais comum é ele não ter código. Normalmente ele é usado para declarar as estruturas de dados mas não definir os algoritmos.

O ideal é não abusar de *includes* dentro de *includes*. Nem sempre isto é possível.

Neste exemplo o compilador provavelmente irá montar algo assim para compilar:

```
/*

todo conteúdo enorme do arquivo string.h aqui

*/

using namespace std;
string a() {
return "PTSO";
}

/*

todo conteúdo enorme do arquivo string.h aqui repetido já que ele já está lá em cima

*/

using namespace std;
int main() {
return 0;
}
```

Há uma técnica para evitar a inclusão repetida de arquivos *include* por acidente. O que não parece ser o caso. Bom, até é porque você fez sem saber que está errado. Mas é um caso que você fez deliberadamente. O acidente ocorre quando vai ficando complexo e você já não consegue mais controlar "de olho" de um *include* já está lá no código ou não.

Vou considerar que este é só um exemplo, porque não faz o menor sentido usar `#include "Header.h"` no código principal. Ele está incluindo algo que não é necessário.

De qualquer forma o normal seria definir a função `a()` dentro do `.cpp` mesmo.

Sempre que puder evitar o uso de *include*, evite. Claro que em uma aplicação real isto é quase impossível. Criar um *include* é necessário quando você vai usar os algoritmos definidos em um `.cpp` em outro arquivo fonte. Quando é certo que só vai usar ali dentro dele mesmo, não precisa criar um `.hpp`.

## Um exemplo melhor

#### auxiliar.cpp

```
#include <string>

std::string a() {
    return "PTSO";
}
```

#### auxiliar.hpp

```
#include <string>

std::string a();
```

#### main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "auxiliar.hpp"

int main() {
    cout << a();
    return 0;
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CPP/Syntax/Include.cpp).

Note que em C++ é comum usar `.hpp`, embora muito programador não o faça até para tentar reutilizar em C. O que daria também com ambas extensões. Eu prefiro usar `.hpp` para deixar claro que aquele código foi escrito em C++.

Comment: Entendi. Coloquei o Header.h apenas para ter um header, rs.

Comment: Além do `.hpp`, há quem use a extensão `.hxx` ou nenhuma extensão para headers C++. Eu prefiro usar `.hpp` pelo mesmo motivo.

Answer (score 7):

A diretiva *#include*, quando executada, faz com que uma cópia do arquivo cujo nome é dado entre < e > seja incluído no código-fonte. Por exemplo, suponha que definimos as macros a seguir e as salvamos num arquivo denominado macros.h:

```
#define quad(n) ( (n)∗(n) )
#define abs(n) ( (n)<0 ? −(n) : (n) )
#define max(x,y) ( (x)>(y) ? (x) : (y) )
```

Então, toda vez que precisarmos de uma destas macros, não será preciso digitá-las novamente; basta solicitar ao preprocessador que inclua uma cópia do arquivo macros.h no início do nosso programa.

Duas observações devem ser feitas a respeito da inclusão de arquivos:

1. Qualquer arquivo, com qualquer extensão, pode ser incluído num
   programa fonte através da diretiva *#include*.
2. A notação < e > é preferencialmente utilizada para arquivos de inclusão padrão da linguagem C. Para incluir arquivos definidos pelo usuário, utilize a notação " e ".

Fonte: [Linguagem C](http://www.ime.usp.br/~slago/slago-C.pdf)

Comment: Este trecho copiado está sem contexto. Eu li e fiquei perdido na explicação. Fora que é sobre C e não C++ (apesar de que é muito parecido).

Comment: Peguei da apostila de C, pela semelhança mesmo, a forma de funcionamento é igual nas duas.

Answer (score 2):

O "include" traz informações sobre a biblioteca, no caso a sua biblioteca está com as funções, ele irá trazer tudo o que estiver nela.

Comment: A resposta não chega estar errada mas esta é uma enorme simplificação do processo. Arquivos de cabeçalho não estão diretamente ligados à bibliotecas. Eventualmente eles são usados para isto.

Answer (score 1):

Você está importando um texto. O que o compilador faz é simplificadamente o mesmo que você copiar e colar o texto que está dentro do include para dentro do texto que está no fonte principal.

Por isto a posição em que ele é incluso é importante. Quase sempre quando você não faz logo no início você está com problemas.

Ele está importando todo seu conteúdo. Normalmente esse conteúdo são apenas declarações de estruturas de dados (classes, estruturas, enumerações), constantes, cabeçalho de funções/métodos, macros e eventualmente algum código quando se deseja que uma função seja importada direto no fonte ao invés de ser chamada (source inline). O mais comum é ele não ter código. Normalmente ele é usado para declarar as estruturas de dados mas não definir os algoritmos.

O ideal é não abusar de includes dentro de includes. Nem sempre isto é possível.

Neste exemplo o compilador provavelmente irá montar algo assim para compilar: