# Duvidas sobre a fase de compilação e "linkagem" de um Programa em C

Tags: c, compilação

Eu tenho algumas perguntas sobre os passos utilizados para a compilação de um programa em C.

Eu tenho como fonte de estudo o livro do Luis Damas (sei que não é aconselhável ter somente uma...), onde ele diz que a fase de compilação consiste na verificação sintática da estrutura do código a ser compilado. Caso não tenha qualquer erro, ele cria um arquivo objeto referente ao arquivo `.c`.
Porém, ele não diz o que tem dentro do código objeto.

Afinal, o que compõe o arquivo objeto?

E quando incluímos um `#include` qualquer no nosso código, o pré-processador insere a biblioteca no nosso programa, ou somente um "link" que informa ao `linker` qual a biblioteca a ser utilizada e onde ela se encontra?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O formato interno dos arquivos objeto varia de compilador para compilador, eles não são obrigados a seguir um padrão sobre isso, mas basicamente o que têm lá é a lista das funções e variáveis globais do seu arquivo .c, já em formato de instruções de máquina. Os *labels* para jumps e chamadas de função ainda são temporários, o linker vai arrumá-los no momento da criação do executável final.

E sobre includes, pense neles sempre como se você desse um ctrl+c ctrl+v do arquivo que você está incluindo no arquivo fonte. O compilador precisa disso pra saber o nome das funções, seus parâmetros e o layout das estruturas de dados. Assim, ao chamar uma função que recebe dois ints o compilador sabe que tem que gerar instruções para colocar esses parâmetros na pilha antes de realizar a chamada. Então sim, é como se fosse um link mesmo, um espaço vazio que o linker depois substitui pelo endereço "real" daquela função no executável.

Answer (score 3):

O `#include` é algo que só serve ao compilador. Já tem [pergunta falando disso](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/45021/101), não tem porque repetir aqui.

Já respondi em linhas gerais [como funciona um compilador](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/104814/101).

O objeto possui essencialmente o código binário que deverá executar. Esse código são bytes que fazem sentido para instruir o processador.

Claro que ele possui algumas informações que ajudam o *linker* montar o executável, tem tabela de símbolos públicos, informações de relocação, dados estáticos gerados, definições de referências, informações para depuração (quando é adequado), etc.

Pode usar o [`objdump`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/objdump) para ver o que tem dentro dele. Ou o [`dumpbin`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/dumpbin-reference?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=msvc-160) se usar Microsoft.

Cada um pode ter um formato [COFF é um dos formatos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/COFF).

Para entender um pouco sobre o [funcionamento do código binário já tem uma pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/142289/101).

O objeto é gerado como unidade única de compilação. O compilador monte conforme é informado, não há uma correlação de um arquivo `.c` e um objeto.

O formato interno não depende do compilador e sim do *linkeditor* que ele quer se conformar. Tem compiladores que possuem *linkeditores* junto então até acaba dando para falar que é formato da ferramenta como um todo.

- [Artigo da Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_file).
- [Artigo com detalhes](https://www.iecc.com/linker/linker03.html).
- [Artigo do OSDev](http://wiki.osdev.org/Object_Files).

Comment: Muito obrigado, eu vou estudar esses artigos. :)