# Pra que serve um linker?

Tags: c, c++, terminologia, linkagem

Algumas linguagens se utilizam de um *linker* ou *likeditor* como também é chamado. Qual é a função dele e a relação com o compilador?

Por que algumas linguagens não possuem um *linker*?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

O *linker* é um utilitário que costuma ser complementar ao [compilador](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/101691/101). Ele pega código binário gerado pelo compilador e junta tudo, daí o nome, em um executável. O executável pode ser algo para chamada direta ou para ligação dinâmica (DLL).

Eventualmente ele pode gerar uma biblioteca com diversos códigos binários e que poderá ser usada mais tarde para gerar um executável. Nesse caso a biblioteca precisa ser especificada para ligar junto.

Muitas vezes o programador iniciante não entende porque ele usou um `#include` mas dá erro que não achou um símbolo (função, variável global, tipos, etc.). Não é problema no código e sim na *linkedição*, faltou especificar onde deve pegar esse símbolo, seja na biblioteca ou em outro binário gerado separado em outro processo de compilação.

É comum que o compilador gere uma unidade de compilação, em alguns contextos chamado de código objeto. Essa unidade pode conter vários fontes. O *linker* junta essas unidades, portanto tudo o que está dentro dele será colocado no executável, mesmo que não vá usar na aplicação. Em linguagens que possuem classes a unidade de compilação pode incluir toda a classe, ou um grupo de classes.

Ele entende como gerar o formato do executável para cada plataforma, e pode fazer algumas otimizações que só são possíveis quando todo o código está junto (LTO). Em geral ele faz uma relocação de endereços internos quando junta tudo.

Linguagens que possuem um *bytecode* ou são interpretadas não possuem *linker* tradicional já que não geram código binário. Algumas dessas linguagens possuem um [JITter](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/146250/101) que gerará o código binário tudo junto.

Tem utilitário que reúne o compilador e o *linkeditor*, então pode parecer que não existe um ligador de binários, mas ele já faz logo em seguida da compilação.

- [Qual a diferença de DLL e lib?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/44269/101)
- [Qual a diferença entre linkagem estática e dinâmica?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/149372/101)
- [Duvidas sobre a fase de compilação e "linkagem" de um Programa em C](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/156114/101)

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Conceptual.md).