# Processo de ligação à bibliotecas (DLL's) durante o processo de compilação de fonte C++

Tags: c++, compilação, dll

Durante o processo de compilação, penso eu, ocorre algum tipo de ligação entre meu código e a biblioteca da qual eu esteja utilizando código. De que forma meu aplicativo fica apto a chamar o código de uma DLL? Ou seja, o que ocorre durante a compilação que promove esse vínculo?

Tudo que eu sei é que uso:

```
#include<library>
using namesmpace nms;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O processo nada tem a ver com o `#include`, menos ainda com o `namespace`.

Isso tem a ver com a [*linkagem*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/191565/101) do código. Quando vai usar alguma DLL o executável é gerado em uma forma que fica indicado que o código exato será pego da DLL no momento da execução e é colocado alguma informação para fazer a ligação chamada dinâmica. Quando chamar o executável ele procurará a DLL e carregará o que for necessário fazendo uma adaptação do endereço provisório que havia sido colocado no executável para o endereço real do código presente na DLL.

A única relação com o `#include` é que a compilação precisa saber as [assinaturas das funções](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/39870/101) que serão chamadas na DLL. Esta é só uma informação para o compilador, o código da DLL não será colocado junto ao seu código. Inclusive se tiver algum erro no cabeçalho você terá problemas durante a execução. O `.h` tem que ter informações sincronizadas com o código que está na DLL.

Comment: Ok. Tudo bem. Mas, aí que está: como é feito esse processo de linkagem? De de forma o executável "referencia" essa DLL? O que os arquivos *.lib têm haver com isso?

Comment: @Paulo essencialmente não precisa fazer nada na maior parte dos casos. A DLL precisa estar disponível e o *header* precisa estar tudo ok. Se tiver uma dúvida mais concreta faça em uma nova pergunta.

Comment: Entendi. Obrigado.

Answer (score 0):

Basicamente,oque acontece é que quando você usa um `#include`,a macro do Sistema Operacional,procura o arquivo .h ou biblioteca dentro do seu computador,e assim que você compila,ele insere o código da biblioteca dinamicamente no seu arquivo.c ou .cpp,assim sendo possível você usar os métodos dessa biblioteca sem mesmo precisar conhecer a sua implementação

Comment: Isto está bem confuso, provavelmente errado.

Comment: foi mal cara,não possuo muita experiência em bibliotecas de vinculos dinâmicos dll's,porém oque acontece com qualquer biblioteca que você inclui no seu código,qualquer .h,é isso basicamente