# Sobre os cabeçalhos no C++

Tags: c++, header, inline

Algumas dúvidas surgiram especificamente sobre a criação de cabeçalhos:

1. Se eu criar uma arquivo teste.h, e um outro teste.cpp, como o compilador C++ faz para relacionar o arquivo teste.cpp com o arquivo teste.h, isto é, quais são os critérios usados? O que impede de que as definições para teste.h em teste.cpp sejam substituídas por outras?
2. (Complemento da pergunta anterior) se criamos um arquivo teste.h e o implementarmos em um arquivo de nome diferente, digamos, prova.cpp, ainda assim o programa compila. Como explicar isso?
3. Porquê o código a seguir não compila? Eu obtenho um erro 'undefined reference to cubo'.

```cpp
/* teste.h */
#ifndef TESTE
#define TESTE

inline double cubo(double a);

#endif // TESTE
```

```cpp
/* Teste.cpp: implementação de Teste.h.*/
#include "teste.h"

double cubo(double a)
{
    return a * a * a;
}
```

```cpp
/* Principal.cpp */
#include <iostream>
#include "teste.h"

int main()
{
    std::cout << cubo(2.0) << std::endl;
}
```

4. Ao implementar uma função **inline** em um arquivo `.cpp`, faz alguma diferença remover o qualificador **inline** da definição da função, deixando apenas na declaração?
5. Li em vários lugares que definir funções **inline** em arquivos de cabeçalho ajuda a prevenir "múltiplas definições de funções". Poderia explicar como essas "múltiplas definições podem ocorrer"?

Estou usando o Qt Creator no Linux (Kubuntu 16.04). O compilador é o gcc (g++).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> Se eu criar uma arquivo teste.h, e um outro teste.cpp, como o compilador C++ faz para relacionar o arquivo teste.cpp com o arquivo teste.h, isto é, quais são os critérios usados? O que impede de que as definições para teste.h em teste.cpp sejam substituídas por outras?

É preciso saber as seguintes coisas:

1) O include coloca o código de um cabeçalho no mesmo lugar onde houve o include. Quer dizer, cabeçalho não é código-fonte para compilar, ele apenas contêm códigos que serão embutidos nos verdadeiros códigos-fonte (esses sim são compilados).

Isso significa que o teste.cpp, devido ao include, dá no mesmo que o que está a seguir (com a diferença que o include tira sua necessidade de copiar todo o cabeçalho para o código-fonte).

```
/* Teste.cpp: implementação de Teste.h.*/

// Começa o #include "teste.h"
/* teste.h */
#ifndef TESTE
#define TESTE

inline double cubo(double a);

#endif // TESTE
// Termina o #include "teste.h"

double cubo( double a )
{
    return a * a * a;
}
```

2) Definir algo é criar essa coisa de modo que possa ser usada no arquivo.cpp onde foi definido. Foi o que você fez no teste.cpp, você definiu a função cubo.

3) Declarar algo é avisar que aquilo existe (mesmo que em outro arquivo) e que aquilo pode ser usado. Foi o que você fez no teste.h, você declarou a função cubo. Sendo assim, onde você incluir o teste.h você estará avisando que pode daí em diante no arquivo fonte usar a função.

Quando você faz o `#include "teste.h"` no teste.cpp, você está botando a declaração de algo que logo a seguir já é definido lá, ou seja, é desnecessário no teste.cpp. O include é necessário somente se o cabeçalho declarar algo que não será definido nem declarado a seguir no mesmo arquivo, que é o caso de main.cpp.

4) Ao compilar os códigos-fonte, há o processo de lincagem. Cada aquivo fonte dá origem a um arquivo objeto com os símbolos usados no código. Esses símbolos dos arquivos objetos são conectados entre si de tal modo que a definição em um código fonte possa ser usada em outro onde se tem a declaração.

Quer dizer que a função cubo tem o símbolo cubo existente em main.cpp (onde é declarado e usado) e teste.cpp (onde é definido e poderia ser usado, mas não é), aí a lincagem possibilita que main.cpp tenha acesso á definição em teste.cpp para que possa usar a função. Sem a lincagem, main.cpp não tem acesso à função cubo definida em teste.cpp.

Observação: não há substituições de definições. Se o lincador encontrar duas, as chamadas são ambíguas e portanto ocorre erro semântico de compilação porque o lincador não vai saber diferenciar a definição que deve ser usada.

> (Complemento da pergunta anterior) se criamos um arquivo teste.h e o implementarmos em um arquivo de nome diferente, digamos, prova.cpp, ainda assim o programa compila. Como explicar isso?

Se declarar no prova.cpp, o prova.cpp poderá usar a função também. Mas se definir lá enquanto está definido em teste.cpp e possibilitar a lincagem de ambos os arquivos, as definições entram em conflito, causam ambiguidade e geram erro de lincagem.

> Porquê o código a seguir não compila? Eu obtenho um erro 'undefined reference to cubo'.

Se a main.cpp usa uma função mas ela não é definida, então esse erro aparece. Para encontrar a definição, o teste.cpp (que tem a definição) tem que ser compilado pra gerar código objeto. Quer dizer que você não está compilando o teste.cpp, logo ele não está sendo lincado. É necessário compilar os dois.

> Ao implementar uma função inline em um arquivo .cpp, faz alguma diferença remover o qualificador inline da definição da função, deixando apenas na declaração?

É necessário definir com inline. Porém esse efeito também depende das opções de compilação, que podem inabilitar inline ou até liberar inline para funções não definidas assim caso o compilador julgue benéfico. Se não me engano, o padrão é chamada de função de um arquivo para outro não gerar código inline.

> Li em vários lugares que definir funções inline em arquivos de cabeçalho ajuda a prevenir "múltiplas definições de funções". Poderia explicar como essas "múltiplas definições podem ocorrer"?

Por exemplo.

```
double Double( int x , double *p ){
    return *p = (double)x ;
}

double Double( int z , double *p ){
    *p = 2.0*z ;
    return *p ;
}
```

Isto é múltipla definição. Duas funções de mesma assinatura (nome e parâmetros `Double(int,double*)`), mesmo sendo funções diferentes, geram ambiguidade. Não tem problema definir em arquivos diferentes (cada arquivo usa a sua função) a não ser que o símbolo seja declarado em algum lugar (pois aí não se sabe de onde lincar aquele, aí dá o erro que abordei anteriormente).

Espero ter esclarecido. Caso contrário, me avise.

Comment: Entendi. Em relação aos itens 1 e 2, eu pensava que havia uma correspondência **um para um** entre arquivos de cabeçalho e arquivos de código fonte. Agora vejo que não é assim. Se eu criar, um cabeçalho MyHeader.h, e declarar nele três funções e implementar cada uma em seu próprio arquivo .cpp, o próprio compilador irá localizá-las e fazer a ligação.

Então, _"o compilador lê os arquivos de cabeçalho e obtém a lista de declarações nesses arquivos. Depois busca em todos os arquivos indicados para compilação as definições para cada uma daquelas declarações"_.

Comment: Em relação ao item 3, o código compila se eu remover o qualificador **inline**. Creio não ter explicado minha questão nesse item de forma completa. A dúvida do item 3 reside em saber _porque o código não compila se eu marcar a função como **inline**_.

Comment: Mais ou menos. O compilador otimiza a procura evitando muitas releituras para agilizar a compilação. É tipo assim: (1) o compilador lê os ".cpp" tratando os ".h" como se fossem parte dele (achou include? deixa um pouco o ".cpp", lê aquele cabeçalho incluido, depois volta de onde parou); (2) na leitura dos arquivos, coleta os dados necessários dos símbolos declarados, definidos e usados; (3) avalia as conexões dos símbolos coletados.

Comment: Agora quanto ao problema do inline, eu fiz um teste. Mantive o inline como estava, mas tirei o include do teste.cpp. Aqui, isso compilou sem erro. Também testei com o include, com o inline e colocando extern antes do inline. Aqui, isso também compilou sem erro. Não entendi bem o que acontece nessas situações envolvendo inline, só sei que tem alguma coisa que altera a visibilidade ou a assinatura da função. Uma coisa é certa: se não é bug, então tem uma lógica por trás disso.

Comment: Em relação ao meu primeiro comentário, estou ciente de que não é uma boa prática criar um MyHeader.h e implementar as declarações dele em vários arquivos. O ideal mesmo é ter um um cabeçalho .h e um arquivo .cpp com o mesmo nome, indicando que estamos declarando e implementando um mesmo conjunto de funcionalidades. Aquele exemplo foi só para entender o que ocorre internamente.

Answer (score 2):

Abaixo ainda consta as perguntas específicas, mas agora entendo que as perguntas na verdade é sobre o erro gerado pelo `inline`.

Sempre que usar o `inline` o código de [implementação](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/111284/101) da função precisa estar na mesma unidade de compilação, não pode estar em outra parte. Não basta ter apenas a [assinatura da função](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/39870/101). Isso é diferente. Como o código da função provavelmente terá que ser usado no seu novo código e não será chamada, o fonte deve estar disponível ali mesmo. Então neste caso o correto é ter o cabeçalho assim:

```
#ifndef TESTE
#define TESTE

double cubo(double a) {
    return a * a * a;
}

#endif // TESTE
```

Veja [funcionando **ideone**](https://ideone.com/Ff2hgU). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/nkcwcfgj-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CPP/Syntax/InlineInHeader.h).

[Documentação sobre o `inline`.](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/inline)

> Se eu criar uma arquivo teste.h, e um outro teste.cpp, como o compilador C++ faz para relacionar o arquivo teste.cpp com o arquivo teste.h, isto é, quais são os critérios usados? O que impede de que as definições para teste.h em teste.cpp sejam substituídas por outras?

Nada, quem faz isso é código, o compilador só faz o que for determinado pelo código.

> (Complemento da pergunta anterior) se criamos um arquivo teste.h e o implementarmos em um arquivo de nome diferente, digamos, prova.cpp, ainda assim o programa compila. Como explicar isso?

Exatamente pelo que está acima, não há vínculos implícitos, o código diz o que ele deve vincular, então funciona com nomes que quiser. Claro que o conteúdo precisa ser adequado.

> Porquê o código a seguir não compila? Eu obtenho um erro 'undefined reference to cubo'.

Isto é erro de [*linkedição*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/191565/101), ele achou todo código, mas não achou o binário necessário para criar o executável. Depende de como está compilando, pode ser só que não adicionou o `.cpp`, pode ser que precise indicar onde o código já compilado anteriormente está. Pode ser um problema na configuração do projeto do IDE.

> Ao implementar uma função inline em um arquivo .cpp, faz alguma diferença remover o qualificador inline da definição da função, deixando apenas na declaração?

De forma geral não faz diferença porque o compilador fará o *inline* se ele quiser. Mas para efeitos de ter o código pode fazer diferença.

Se você diz que é *inline* tem que ter ali naquela unidade de compilação um código executável dessa função, e provavelmente você não colocou. Quando não o usa pode ser que isso seja resolvido em outro lugar.

> Li em vários lugares que definir funções inline em arquivos de cabeçalho ajuda a prevenir "múltiplas definições de funções". Poderia explicar como essas "múltiplas definições podem ocorrer"?

A pergunta está um pouco ampla, mas a grosso modo o cabeçalho é um centralizador, lá é o local correto para colocar as funções *inline* já que ela serão usadas onde precisa. Se começa espalhá-las por arquivos diversos quem garante que todas são a mesma?

Comment: O código do exemplo que dei compila se eu remover o qualificador **inline**. Foi falha minha não ter explicado isso antes.

Comment: @MuriloNeto agora entendi sua real dúvida, editei a resposta e dei uma solução para o problema.

Comment: Entendi. A documentação que você indicou me ajudou também a entender como ocorrem as múltiplas definições. A documentação informa que "funções incluídas em múltiplos arquivos fonte devem ser inline". Depois de ler e reler percebi que o que se está tentando dizer ali é que (minha interpretação) "se você definir a função no próprio arquivo de cabeçalho, marque-a como inline, porque senão, ao tentar incluir o cabeçalho onde a função foi definida em vários arquivos de código fonte, ela será copiada para cada arquivo de código fonte e ocorrerá o erro de múltiplas definições."