# Por que tem que se adicionar opção -pthread ao compilar com a biblioteca thread do std?

Tags: c++, thread, gcc, clang

Se no `main.cpp` eu uso a biblioteca *thread* do `std`, para compilar tenho que usar o seguinte comando:

```
g++ main.cpp -pthread
```

E  mesmo se aplica ao clang.

Este e o único caso que conheço da biblioteca padrão em que tem que se adicionar alguma opção extra ao compilar. Porquê tem que se adicionar a opção `-pthread`? Porquê não pode ser como as outras bibliotecas do `std`? Já pesquisei sobre isso, mas não achei nada útil.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Na verdade existem outras bibliotecas que precisa isto. As principais bibliotecas estão juntas em um arquivo binário que sempre é usado na hora de fazer a [*linkedição*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/191565/101). As bibliotecas que não estão dentro deste binário precisam ser especificadas para *linkar* individualmente.

É separado porque algumas coisas não são tão padrões assim, então pode ser que alguém queira substituir a implementação por outra.