# Como fazer um arquivo C ler uma variavel que esta dentro de um shell script?

Tags: c, variáveis, shell

Boa tarde,
eu escrevi um código de teste em shellscript chamado copilador.sh
nele, eu peço para o usuário digitar no terminal o nome da pessoa a ser avaliada
e isso é armazenado numa variável que chamo de choose.
O problema é que eu gostaria de passar essa mesma variável para um script C.

então o codigo shell é este:

```
sleep 1
echo -choose "ENTRE COM O NICKNAME DO CAMPER A SER AVALIADO: "
read -p choose
sleep 1
```

e o código c é este:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "/home/coder/avaliados/$choose/ex00/ft_putchar.c"
```

alguem poderia me ajudar?

Comment: Eu acho que tu podes chamar o executável que fizeste em C e passar o que foi lido no script como parâmetro de entrada para o programa C. Isso seria uma opção para ti?

Comment: Poderia ser, como funcionaria?

Comment: Dá uma olhada [nesse tutorial](http://linguagemc.com.br/argumentos-em-linha-de-comando/) e vê se te ajuda

Comment: Obrigado, mas nao funcionou nao.

Comment: A variavel ja foi alocada pelo shell script, eu preciso passar essa variavel para o caminho do include para que desta maneira ele leia o main.c de outro local, sem ser aonde estou no momento.

Comment: Outra opção seria salvar em um arquivo, e fazer o programa C ler esse arquivo...

Comment: No código C $choose é a variável? Ou seja, vc tem vários diretórios com $choose/ex00/ft_putchar.c

Comment: Não se você sabe mas diretiva `#include` é resolvida em tempo de compilação, veja [Como funciona a diretiva "#include"](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/45021/como-funciona-a-diretiva-include). Caso seu objetivo seja obter um código que modifique o seu comportamento após ser compilado baseado numa Macro definida pelo shell script não vai conseguir.

Answer (score -1):

Note:

- A variável de ambiente deixa de existir ao final do script. Para continuar valendo depois do final do script ela deve ser exportada
- Um `#define` é resolvido em tempo de compilação. É um comando para o pré-processador e o compilador vai gerar um trecho de código a partir disso. Numa outra fase --- `link` --- esse e possíveis outros trechos de código como outros arquivos C e bibliotecas vão gerar um programa executável. E esse código nada sabe sobre o script e o ambiente em que os arquivos que compõem o programa foram compilados.
- o script pode rodar anos depois do programa ter sido compilado e não existe mais isso de `#define`.
- Programas como `make` e `CMake` (e todo IDE) permitem usar variáveis de ambiente para configurar a geração de código.
- Em C você pode chamar `getenv()` e obter os valores de variáveis de ambiente no **momento da execução do programa**, mas nada tem a ver com `#define`

Comment: Considerando a pergunta e o que eu disse dá para imaginar que minha resposta seja marcada como inútil... Ou não. Ah o SO e os plantonistas que não leêm as próprias recomendações do site.